# Increment in Oracle Forms without commit record

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

I have used this code to generating an auto number:

```
DECLARE
ACC_NEW_ID NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
if :acc_info_id is null then
SELECT MAX(NVL(ACC_INFO_ID,1000))+1 INTO ACC_NEW_ID FROM ACC_INFO;
:ACC_INFO_ID := ACC_NEW_ID;
end if;
END;
```

This code is working perfectly, but when I create one further record without clicking save button it creates the same number. For example: id is 1003 and after posting the record, I clicked new record button instead of save button, It generates the same 1003 number instead of 1004 as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code queries the records in the table, and returns the maximum ID *that it can see at that point in time* (i.e. it won't see uncommitted records), and adds one to it.

If it generates 1003 but no record with this value is saved into the table, of course you should expect it to not find it!

As far as that is concerned, it "works perfectly" and correctly. If, however, the intention is to generate a unique ID value for each record, this approach is flawed and will fail in any normal system due to concurrency.

Instead, if you need a unique ID you should use an Oracle SEQUENCE instead, which guarantees uniqueness.